# Selecting a string until the first period after 100 characters

Tags: ruby, string

I can select the first 100 characters of a string by doing

```
string[0..99]
```

I can select up to the first period by doing

```
string.split('.').first
```

But what if I wanted to select the string up until the first period after 100 characters? This means:

1. The number of characters has to be greater than 100
2. After the character count passes 100, the string must stop at the first period.

How would I do this in Ruby?

Comment: `string[0..100]` doesn't give the first 100; it gives the first 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regexp

```
string[/\A.{100,}?\./]
```

Comment: This is greedy and will stop at the last `.`. Try `string[/\A.{100,}?\./]`.

Comment: @sawa That depends on how you want to handle multiline strings

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
string[/.{100}[^.]*\./]
```

You can also do it as

```
string[/.{100}.*?\./]
```

but it is less efficient.